# Python doesn't see a module

Tags: python, module, init

I'm new in python , and in the first place I've encountered a "Module not found error" , My folder structure is the following. I need to access the a.py , and b.py file from c.py file.

```
dir_1
    ├── __init__.py
    └── a.py
    └── b.py
dir_2
    └── c.py
```

I've tried to add all file in my **init**.py as follow

```
from .ImageToOcr import *
from .TM_pilot_card_numbers import *
```

but result doesn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few solutions:

- Within your IDE (e.g. PyCharm) add those directories as Sources Root
- Refer to the modules with relative pathing
- Install the module into your environment
- Add the folders to your code to look in as sys.path.append('dir_1')

Comment: I have followed the second suggestion , i refer to my module with relative path like this :  import sys     sys.path.append(r"./")  . And it works    .   Is this the best solution for my problem?

Comment: "Best" is always depending on the exact use case. Once you have modules that you want to reuse often, inside different environments, maybe creating an installable package is preferred. If you are using PyCharm to run the code, maybe it's convenient to use its built-in function to designate folders as Roots. As far as I know sys append works in any case.